# Query on Sqlite to group only the three most recent records for each user

Tags: sqlite

I have a complex query on Sqlite to run. Please consider the table below.

I will need three most recent record for each userID and BatchID and the sum of status. I will also need a count of the number of records for each result.

For example, given that userID U6TH16003 has only 1 record, the record count will be 1. User U6TH15001 has 7 records, only the 3 most recent records will be considered and status filed added for the 3 most recent record for the user which gives 2 and the total number of records considered for the sum of status field is 3.

```
Date        UserID      Status
2016-11-14  U6TH16001   0   
2016-11-17  U6TH16001   0   
2016-11-07  U6TH16001   1   
2016-11-01  U6TH16001   0   
2016-10-20  U6TH16002   1   
2016-10-15  U6TH16002   1   
2016-10-10  U6TH16002   1   
2016-11-14  U6TH16003   1   
2016-11-17  U6TH15001   1   
2016-11-14  U6TH15001   0   
2016-11-07  U6TH15001   1   
2016-11-01  U6TH15001   0   
2016-10-28  U6TH15001   1   
2016-10-23  U6TH15001   1   
2016-10-15  U6TH15001   1
```

The output that I need for the above table is as below:

```
UserID          Sum(Status)     NumberOfRecords
U6TH16001       1               3
U6TH16002       3               3
U6TH16003       1               1
U6TH15001       2               3
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This would require some sort of row number functionality, which unfortunately SQLite does not have built in.

Comment: I have tried something like this so far.:select UserID, SUM(Att_status) from Table group by userid)). And it is returning me for all records, is there a way to consider only the three most?

Comment: The problem with your attempt is that `LIMIT` will apply to the entire query.  But you want to apply it to each group.  Other RDBMS have a row number function which could be used to retain the top 3 rows from each group.  In SQLite, you will have to simulate this behavior somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get all user IDs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM MyTable;
```

Then for each such user ID, determine the smallest date that we want to handle, by sorting that user's records by the date, and picking the third one:

```
SELECT UserID,
       (SELECT Date
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE UserID = Users.UserID
        ORDER BY Date DESC
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
       ) AS MinDate
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UserID
      FROM MyTable
     ) AS Users;
```

```
UserID     MinDate
U6TH16001  2016-11-07
U6TH16002  2016-10-10
U6TH16003  NULL
U6TH15001  2016-11-07
```

Then we can join these values back with the original table to get only the desired records, and finally do the aggregation over them:

```
SELECT MyTable.UserID,
       SUM(Status),
       COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
JOIN (SELECT UserID,
             (SELECT Date
              FROM MyTable
              WHERE UserID = Users.UserID
              ORDER BY Date DESC
              LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
             ) AS MinDate
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UserID
            FROM MyTable
           ) AS Users
     ) AS MinDates
     ON MyTable.UserID = MinDates.UserID
    AND MyTable.Date  >= IFNULL(MinDates.MinDate, 0)
GROUP BY MyTable.UserID;
```

Comment: This is what I needed :) Working perfectly. Thanks a lot CL.